# MixedUnit in Fractions

Tags: units

Is there a way to have a more common output format on [`MixedUnit`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MixedUnit.html)?

```
Quantity[317.2,MixedUnit[{"Minutes"/"Kilometers", "Seconds"/"Kilometers"}]]
```

gives

[image]

I would love to have some unit like $$\frac{317\,\text{min } 12\, \text{s}}{km}$$

```
Quantity[317.2, MixedUnit[{"Minutes", "Seconds"}]/"Kilometers"]
```

gives an error

[image]

Comment: With v13.2 on my Mac your first example evaluates to `{Quantity[MixedMagnitude[{317, 0}], MixedUnit[{("Minutes")/("Kilometers"), ("Seconds")/("Kilometers")}]], Quantity[MixedMagnitude[{12., 0}], MixedUnit[{("Minutes")/("Kilometers"), ("Seconds")/("Kilometers")}]]}` to get your result I need `Quantity[MixedMagnitude[{IntegerPart[#], 60*FractionalPart[#]} &[317.2]], MixedUnit[{"Minutes"/"Kilometers", "Seconds"/"Kilometers"}]]`

Comment: @BobHanlon I used v13.0 on Windows, but seems strange if the output differs so much between some minor releases.

Comment: **UnitConvert[Quantity[317.2, "Seconds"/"Kilometers"], 
  MixedUnit[{"Minutes", "Seconds"}/"Kilometers"]]** --> *5 min/km 17.2 s/km*

Comment: Try 2: **UnitConvert[Quantity[317.2, "Minutes"/"Kilometers"]*Quantity["Kilometers"], 
  MixedUnit[{"Minutes", "Seconds"}]]/"km"** ==> $\frac{317\, \text{min}\ 12.\text{s}}{\text{km}}$